# Using a multiple select field to handle semantic_fields_for related objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-many, formtastic, fields-for

I have a `Post` which can have multiple `Tags`, each of which relates to a `User` (think Facebook tagging).

In my Post form I have this Formtastic code:

```
<%= f.inputs :class => 'tags' do %>

    <ul>
    <%= f.semantic_fields_for :tags do |t| %>   
        <% if t.object.new_record? %>
            <%= t.input :user_id, :label => "&nbsp;", :input_html => { :class => 'chosen', :'data-placeholder' => 'Select connection' }, :as => :select, :collection => current_user.connections %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>   
    </ul>

    <% if @post.tags.present? && !@post.new_record? %>
        <ul class="existing-tags">
        <%= f.fields_for :tags do |t| %>
            <% unless t.object.new_record? %>
                <li>
                    <%= link_to avatar(t.object.user), user_path(t.object.user) %>
                    <%= t.check_box :_destroy %>
                    <%= t.label :_destroy, 'Remove' %>
                </li>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
        <% end %>

<% end %>
```

As you can see this can allow a tag to be added one at a time. However I'd like to allow multiple selections in the dropdown menu, to create multiple tags in one go. Adding "multiple" doesn't work, however: it simply results in creating a tag for the current user, posting the Post.

Can anyone suggest a way I can use a single select field to create multiple tags?

Comment: I am interested in the solution to this as well.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party, but I solved this problem using the awesome [jQuery Chosen plugin](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) which makes multiple selects look really good.